# Adding a projection in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I am following [these](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/faq.html#what-projection-is-openlayers-using-) instructions in order to define my projection for my map. And then use the ol.proj.transform function to transform the coordinates. So my code snippet is the following:

```
  var myProjection = new ol.proj.Projection({
      code: 'EPSG:2100',
      extent: [104022.946289, 3850785.500488, 1007956.563293, 4624047.765686],
      units: 'm'
       });   

    ol.proj.addProjection(myProjections);   

    var center = new ol.proj.transform([21.767997, 39.556105], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:2100');
```

However if I try to console.log(center) the coordinates are not transformed. I'm still getting the same coordinates which are

```
21.767997, 39.556105
```

Does this mean that the addProjection didn't work??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately, that means it didnt work.

So do the following:

include the proj4js library within your project:

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.15/proj4.js`

And then make ol3 aware about EPSG:2100 by adding this line:

`proj4.defs("EPSG:2100","+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=24 +k=0.9996 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=-199.87,74.79,246.62,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");`

To add the extent (if you need it), do

```
ol.proj.get('EPSG:2100').setExtent([104022.946289, 3850785.500488, 1007956.563293, 4624047.765686]);
```

Finally use your new "known" projection as follows

`var center1 = ol.proj.transform([21.767997, 39.556105], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:2100');`

Or

`var center1 = ol.proj.transform([21.767997, 39.556105], 'EPSG:4326', ol.proj.get('EPSG:2100'));`

And here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/b9ogf85L/) to see it in action

Comment: @ahocevar. Thanks for edits and tips . I have also updated the fiddle

Comment: Nice. It works. I was aware of the proj4js library but I thought the solution provided by the link in my answer would be sufficient. Any idea why it didn't work?

Comment: Well, seems that the doc your provide is not very clear. But you should better rely on live examples. -->https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/?q=projection. There are few of them which may help you.

Comment: I just noticed that whatever I do, OpenLayers will by default render the WMS service with SRS 3857. Even if I set in my metadata section "wms_srs" 'ESPG:2100' and in LAYER metadata as well, OpenLayers will try the GetMap request with EPSG:3857 and if I've set to something else it will throw this error: "WMS server error. Invalid CRS given : CRS must be valid for all requested layers". So what's the point in reprojecting if I always have to advertise my WMS data in 3857 ?

Comment: Might be something wrong on the way you do it. You have varius options to deal with reprojection(client side, server side). check this example-->https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-image.html?q=projection but you should better make a new question to demonstrate your case!

Comment: Well... this one works for me:  http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-image-custom-proj.html    Thank you for the help so far