# WFS to JSON vector layer error when specifying srsname in query string, no features when specifying value of DefaultCRS in OpenLayers 4?

Tags: openlayers, wfs

I'm following the [example from the official OL site](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html) for WFS, but I cannot get it to work with a different Feature Server when I add `srsname=` to the query string as specified in the example:

```
GET http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/geometry/senstadt/re_spielplatzbestand/?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typenames=fis:re_spielplatzbestand&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&bbox=1451195.2005082138,6878797.486467866,1529696.0285570899,6909372.297781937,EPSG:3857

Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Response Body:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" version="2.0.0">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="service">
    <ows:ExceptionText>parameter SRSNAME invalid</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Leaving `srsname` out produces a response with 0 features:

```
GET http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/geometry/senstadt/re_spielplatzbestand/?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typenames=fis:re_spielplatzbestand&outputFormat=application/json&bbox=1451195.2005082138,6878797.486467866,1529696.0285570899,6909372.297781937
{
  "type":"FeatureCollection",
  "totalFeatures":0,
  "features":[],
  "crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:25833"}}
}
```

I also tried with `srsname=EPSG:25833` and appending `.EPSG:25833` for the respective bits in `url: function(extent)` since it is the default projection that appears in `GetCapabilities`, but got the same result.

https://jsfiddle.net/bapms31j

Without the `bbox` filter, the URL for `GetFeatures` returns [1809 features](http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/geometry/senstadt/re_spielplatzbestand/?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typenames=fis:re_spielplatzbestand&outputFormat=application/json), so it's definitely not a problem from the Feature Service. The same WFS vector layer works flawlessly in QGIS:

[image: QGSI screenshot]

Also tried changing `version` to `1.0.0` and `1.1.0` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem of projections:

The WFS allows only requests usings SRID 25833. A working example, including the bounding box parameter, is http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/geometry/senstadt/re_spielplatzbestand/?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typenames=fis:re_spielplatzbestand&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:25833&bbox=392215,5818350,393129,5817949,EPSG:25833

Your OpenLayers map uses SRID 3857 as default. So, when including the current map extent using `extent.join(',');`, OpenLayers sends the bounding box in SRID:3857 coordinates whereas the WFS expects coordinates in SRID 25833.

Solution:

1. Transform your bounding box parameters from SRID 3857 to SRID 25833.
2. Transform the received features from SRID 25833 to SRID 3857 before viewing on the map.

Comment: _I also tried with srsname=EPSG:25833 and appending .EPSG:25833 for the respective bits in url: function(extent) since it is the default projection that appears in GetCapabilities, but got the same result._

Comment: Any pointers as to how to perform the transformation you suggest specifically? I.e. with respect to the `extent` parameter to the url function.

Comment: Based on [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179051/openlayers-3-create-bounding-extent-which-includes-two-points) question, tried `ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857'), ol.proj.get('EPSG:25833'));`, but get `TypeError: b is null ol.js:36:29` in the browser

Comment: EPSG:25833 is not supported in OpenLayers by default (only 4326 and 3857, see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.proj.Projection.html ). [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226888/adding-a-projection-in-openlayers) you can find an example for adding a new projection.

Comment: That was bit more work than I anticipated for something at first glance so simple :\ Thanks for the pointers, I finally got it working with the linked question 